# Creating matching list counter

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists like this:

```
list = [[11, 12, 13, 14] [15, 16, 17]]
```

I want to measure the length of each sublist

```
t=[]
for item in list[0]:
t.append(len(item))
```

Now I want to create a matching list of lists that will consists of string "Point" and a number from list length previously measured:

new_list=[]

```
new_list = "Point" += (x)

for i in t:
x = i+1
new_list.append (("Point" += (x) += "="))
```

I hope to end up with a list of lists that will look like this

new_list = [[Point 1, Point 2, Point 3, Point 4][Point 1, Point 2, point 3 ]]
How would i put that together properly?

Thank you,

Konrad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and `range`.  Unlike your earlier question, we don't need to have anything count how many total elements we've seen.

```
>>> seq = [[11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17]]
>>> nseq = [["Point {}".format(i) for i in range(1, len(sub)+1)] for sub in seq]
>>> nseq
[['Point 1', 'Point 2', 'Point 3', 'Point 4'], ['Point 1', 'Point 2', 'Point 3']]
```